# Is there a formula for $1+\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3}+\cdots+\sqrt{N}$?

Tags: calculus, number-theory, elementary-number-theory, summation, recreational-mathematics

Is there a known formula to the sum
$$1+\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3}+\cdots+\sqrt{N}$$
where $N$ is some natural number? Thanks

Comment: Hi. Since this is your first question here, I thought I'd point you to some useful links. Take a look at: [how to ask questions in such a way to maximise your chances of getting them answered](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask). Also, please, in the future, search first before posting new questions. Your question has been asked many, many times here already. Take a [look](http://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=sum+of+square+roots).

Comment: That one asks for an *estimate*, this one asks for a formula.